# Not getting expected results from Swagger 2.0 schema when using object as input

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to build a Swagger definition file that takes an *object* for input, but the object will have ad-hoc field names at runtime.  I'm almost there, but can't seem to get the desired results.  Here is the relevant yaml:

```
/connector_properties/{connector_name}:
    x-swagger-router-controller: contentBridge
    put:
      description: Sets properties for the specified connector
      operationId: setConnectorProperties
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      parameters:
      - name: connector_name
        in: path
        description: The name of the connector
        required: true
        type: string
      - name: connector_properties
        in: body
        description: The properties to assign to the connector
        required: true
        schema:
          type: object
          additionalProperties:
            type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/ParmResponse"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

The connector_name parameter works fine, but the connector_properties parameter only lets me add one field to the object. Additional fields just get added to the value of the first field. For example, if I enter

```
query=somequery
stuff=otherstuff
```

for this field in the swagger-ui page, (and *ecc* for the connector_name) my program receives

```
{
    "connectorName": "ecc",
    "properties": {
    "query": "somequery\nstuff=otherstuff"
    }
}
```

Am I defining it wrong, entering the values wrong, or both?  How can I have multiple ad-hoc fields in this input parameter object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like my YAML is correct for what I want to do. Apparently either Swagger-UI has a bug in this regard, or I don't know how to enter the parameters correctly (probably the latter).  If I use an external tool such as Postman to send the request instead of Swagger-UI, then I get the behavior that I expected.